# Multi-tenant deployment using Shared Image gallery

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a VM in Tenant-2 with Shared Image Galley available in Tenant-1.

Below is the code I am using.

#### TENANT - 2

```
provider "azurerm" {

  subscription_id = "${var.subscription_id}"

  client_id       = "${var.client_id}"

  client_secret   = "${var.client_secret}"

  tenant_id       = "${var.tenant_id}"
}
```

#### TENANT - 1

Provider for fetching the SIG resource

```
provider "azurerm" {

  alias           = "sig-resources-id"

  subscription_id = "${var.sig_subscription_id}"

  client_id       = "${var.sig_client_id}"

  client_secret   = "${var.sig_client_secret}"

  tenant_id       = "${var.sig_tenant_id}"

}
```

From Tenant-1, I am getting the Image ID and use this in azurerm_virtual_machine for VM creation in Tenant-2

> `Error: compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: Code="LinkedAuthorizationFailed" Message="The client has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/galleries/images/versions/read' on scope  '/subscriptions/subscription-ID-of-tenant-2/resourceGroups/mygroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/sigvm-01', however the current tenant '<Tenant-2 ID>' is not authorized to access linked subscription '<subscription-ID-of-tenant-1>'."`

ANY help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed here https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/4290

As per the fix, please add the property `auxiliary_tenant_ids = [""]` as below to Tenant - 1

```
provider "azurerm" {

  subscription_id = "${var.subscription_id}"

  client_id       = "${var.client_id}"

  client_secret   = "${var.client_secret}"

  tenant_id       = "${var.tenant_id}"

  auxiliary_tenant_ids = ["${var.sig_tenant_id}"]
}
```

Hope this helps!